# Inheriting properties without inheritance

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, composition

I've got a strange question here, and I suppose the answer is no, but... is there any way of inheriting a class' prooperties **without inheriting** it, just by composition?

What I got now is something like this:

```
Public Class Mixer
    Inherits SomeOtherClass

    Private _motor As Motor

    Public Property Active() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _motor.Active
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _motor.Active = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Frecuency() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _motor.Frecuency
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _motor.Frecuency = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'More properties and functions from Mixer class, not from Motor
    '
    '
End Class
```

So I need the class Mixer to show publicly all it's Motor properties, but I don't want to inherit Motor since I it already inherits from SomeOtherClass. Is there any faster, cleaner and easier way of doing this?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Just for clarifying: I know I could use an interface, but since the implementation of Motor is the same for all classes, I would like to inherit its properties directly, without having to implement them again in each class that has a Motor... but without inheriting Motor.

Comment: Have you looked into an interface?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx .

Comment: Yeah, of course, but implementing an interface would make me code all the interface's properties implementations, and that's just what I want to avoid...

Comment: What your code looks like right now is a perfect solution if you just make `Motor` and `Mixer` implement a common interface, say, `IMotor`.

Comment: Mixer could inherits from SomeOtherClassWithMotor that inherits SomeOtherClass and adds a motor.

Comment: Lotus has it. If you're adding motors to lots of things, you can create an IMotor interface, and create abstract classes that inherit what you want & additionally implement Motor's Properties for you. Your Mixer class would simply Inherit from SomeClassWithMotor. You have to ask what you're buying for all that complexity though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use properties within an interface and then implement that interface.

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593413/how-to-implement-a-property-in-a-interface)

Answer (score 0):

You could always make your private _motor a public property then you'd be able to get to the Motor properties indirectly. I know it's not quite what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The most widely accepted solution (if not the only solution) is to extract a common interface that is implemented in every class that wraps an instance of `Motor`.

```
Public Interface IMotor

    Property Active As Boolean

    Property Frequency As Boolean

End Interface


Public Class Motor
    Implements IMotor

    Public Property Active As Boolean Implements IMotor.Active

    Public Property Frequency As Boolean Implements IMotor.Frequency

End Class


Public Class Mixer
    Inherits SomeOtherClass
    Implements IMotor

    Private _motor As Motor

    Public Property Active() As Boolean Implements IMotor.Active
        Get
            Return _motor.Active
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _motor.Active = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Frequency() As Boolean Implements IMotor.Frequency
        Get
            Return _motor.Frequency
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _motor.Frequency = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```